# report sync throws fetch error in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, repo

I have three gerrit repos from where I will be doing ""repo sync".

When I do manually repo sync it works fine, but if the same is triggered via a jenkins job it is throwing the following error

```
Fetching proerror: Cannot fetch fss_basic
error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

And it happens only for a specific gerrit repo server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to create ssh key for an user in the PC which is logged in with his account (linux platform) and tried adding those ssh keys in the gerrit server with logged in with my account as that guy was on vacation.

Then I asked that guy to add those ssh keys in the gerrit server with his account logged in, it started to fetch without any error.